# How to Design and Deploy a Custom Trust Association Interceptor for IBM WAS 8

Tags: java, security, websphere, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have set up Idp initiated SSO with OneLogin as IdP and WebSphere as SP. Have been able to successfully get a user to login to my Portal Application when user accesses a link for the same on IdP end (using IBM default ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor).

The problem now is that after login, the portal app needs to load some user specific information in dynamic cache for all portlets to display/function. So I am trying to write a Custom Trust Association Interceptor but am unable to figure to deploy it on Websphere. The IBM docs mention to create a new interceptor class and create default Custom properties but does not mentions what those properties are.

Also, inside my Custom Interceptor, how do I access the SAML response sent by the IdP and extract attributes from the same.

Another functionality that needs to be implemented is that if the user Id passed in SAML Response by IdP does not exists in application at SP end, the user should automatically get created and then logged in to the application at SP end. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Any working examples or code pointers on the above queries will be really appreciated.

Below is a very basic code which I have tried to write for the Custom Interceptor. Here the "callCustomInterceptor" is a query parameter which I'll be sending in the Relay State URL and "uid" is the user id of the user which will be coming in SAML response. Will this work ?

```
enter code here
private static final String CUSTOM_TAI_VERSION = "1.0.0";
private static final String CUSTOM_TAI_TYPE = "Custom Trust Association Interceptor";

@Override
public void cleanup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside cleanup Method #####*****");
}

@Override
public String getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside getType Method #####*****");
    return CUSTOM_TAI_TYPE;
}

@Override
public String getVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside getVersion Method #####*****");
    return CUSTOM_TAI_VERSION;
}

@Override
public int initialize(Properties arg0) throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Inside initialize Method #####*****");
    System.out.println("*****##### Initializing Custom SSO TAI #####*****");
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isTargetInterceptor(HttpServletRequest arg0) throws WebTrustAssociationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Entering isTargetInterceptor Method #####*****");

    System.out.println("Determining if this TAI should handle the incoming request...");

    if (arg0.getParameter("callCustomInterceptor") != null) {
        System.out.println("callCustomInterceptor: " + arg0.getParameter("callCustomInterceptor"));
        System.out.println("Custom SSO TAI is being used to establish trust!");
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println("Bypassing Custom SSO TAI, did not find a user ID in the request");
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Exiting isTargetInterceptor Method #####*****");

    return false;
}

@Override
public TAIResult negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
        throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Entering negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust Method #####*****");
    String userId = arg0.getParameter("uid");
    if (userId.equals("portalUser")) {
        System.out.println("*********** CustomSSOTAI *****************");
        System.out.println("UserID = " + userId);
        return TAIResult.create(SipServletResponse.SC_OK, userId);
    }

    System.out.println("*****##### Custom SSO TAI - Exiting negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust Method #####*****");
    return TAIResult.create(SipServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, userId);
}
```

PS: SAML response is signed only.

Any pointers would help.

**Warm Regards,**
*Ekansh*